# How to revoke all permission on facebook api using rest api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I trying to revoke all permission on withdrawl user
facebook document said will be conducted by calling Url with 'user access token or app access token

> [https://graph.facebook.com/me/{user_id}/permissions](https://graph.facebook.com/me/%7Buser_id%7D/permissions)

but i cant attaching user access token in this request, but i can attach app access token in query params.
so i requested this url with app access token, but response message is
"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Can I really request it with an app access token?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`/me/{user_id}/` makes no sense as request path here.

You either use `/me`, in combination with a user or page token - then that alias will resolve to the actual ID of the entity the token belongs to.
Or you use an app-scoped user ID directly.

If you want to perform any actions on a user account using the app access token, then you must use the second version.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/permissions?access_token={app_access_token}
```

Comment: Thanks! but app access token not working. api response messaging
'A user access token is required to request this resource.'. using access token not working on this API...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking says both for deletion of individual permissions, as well as all of them at the same time, a user token or an app token could be used. If this doesn't work with the app token, I'd file a bug report and ask for clarification.